# Printing a binary buffer in readable Hex format instead of ASCII format

Tags: perl

I have a binary buffer $data which has some hex data and if I print it, I'd get this :

```
$VAR1 = '☺, ?♥☻♦\' N v ►☻ ☻ ◄☻   ↕♥    ‼♥    ¶♥    §* ☺♥☺♥☺@☺ ☺☺☺♠☺♠☺ ☺♦ ☺♀         ☺☻ ☺3
```

which obviously makes no sense to me. But it would be very helpful if I can print it as :

```
8F 00 8F 13 D0 21 A5 25 A3 DA CA 00 01 82 00 80 03 02 04 27 00 4E 00 76
```

instead.

I tried using `sprintf("%x", $data)`, but that doesn't help.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're not too fussy on the format,

```
sprintf("%v02X", $bytes)
```

will give you

```
8F.00.8F.13....
```

If you really want

```
8F 00 8F 13 ...
```

Then the following are some options:

```
sprintf("%v02X", $bytes) =~ s/\./ /rg
```

```
join ' ', map { sprintf("%02X", ord($_)) } split(//, $bytes)
```

```
join ' ', unpack '(H2)*', $bytes
```

Comment: or: `print "$_ " for unpack("(H2)*", $VAR1);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) function:

```
$VAR1 = '☺, ?♥☻♦\' N v ►☻ ☻ ◄☻   ↕♥    ‼♥    ¶♥    §* ☺♥☺♥☺@☺ ☺☺☺♠☺♠☺ ☺♦ ☺♀         ☺☻ ☺3';

print join ' ', map {sprintf("%x", ord)} split //, $VAR1;
```

Outputs:

```
e2 98 ba 2c 20 3f e2 99 a5 e2 98 bb e2 99 a6 27 20 4e 20 76 20 e2 96 ba e2 98 bb 20 e2 98 bb 20 e2 97 84 e2 98 bb 20 20 20 e2 86 95 e2 99 a5 20 20 20 20 e2 80 bc e2 99 a5 20 20 20 20 c2 b6 e2 99 a5 20 20 20 20 c2 a7 2a 20 e2 98 ba e2 99 a5 e2 98 ba e2 99 a5 e2 98 ba 40 e2 98 ba 20 e2 98 ba e2 98 ba e2 98 ba e2 99 a0 e2 98 ba e2 99 a0 e2 98 ba 20 e2 98 ba e2 99 a6 20 e2 98 ba e2 99 80 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 e2 98 ba e2 98 bb 20 e2 98 ba 33
```

Note: if your data is [`utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html), then you'll need to specify it as such:

```
263a 2c 20 3f 2665 263b 2666 27 20 4e 20 76 20 25ba 263b 20 263b 20 25c4 263b 20 20 20 2195 2665 20 20 20 20 203c 2665 20 20 20 20 b6 2665 20 20 20 20 a7 2a 20 263a 2665 263a 2665 263a 40 263a 20 263a 263a 263a 2660 263a 2660 263a 20 263a 2666 20 263a 2640 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 263a 263b 20 263a 33
```

Comment: The OP is aiming for a "helpful" format.  Having a utf8 character listed with its actual value is helpful.

Comment: What <strike>UTF-8</strike>Unicode character?? He didn't say anything about the *binary buffer* being UTF-8, and it's very unlikely to be. Does that look like text to you? 8F 00 8F 13 isn't even valid UTF-8!

Comment: @ikegami I do not know what the OP's data is.  All I can go based off of is what he's posted which were multioctet characters.

Comment: Re "I do not know what the OP's data is", Why not? He posted it. It's `8F 00 8F 13 D0 21 A5 25 A3 DA CA 00 01 82 00 80 03 02 04 27 00 4E 00 76 `

Comment: Re "All I can go based off of is what he's posted which were multioctet characters", huh? He only showed characters from the ASCII character set.

Comment: He posted two data pieces that do not coincide.  Is the first string relevant?  Or is the second string which could just be an example of a suggested desired format?  I don't know.

Comment: Thanks so much you two. your submission and follow up comments actually help me understand a lot better. By the way, the original $data is obtained as raw binary data, and representing them as hex helps me to see the bytes so that I can correctly unpack them. The second string was an example of the desired suggested format. Thanks again so much.